# Returning results with yesterdays date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a join that returns results for today but i want it to return yesterdays values.

```
FROM
Person
JOIN Profit 
ON Person.id = Profit.id 
AND [DATE] = CAST(getdate () -1  as Date)
```

^^ This returns the current date.

I have then tried to return yesterdays date:

```
 [DATE] = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)

 [DATE] = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE())-1,0)

 [DATE] = dateadd(DD, -1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

But none of these work. Can anyone help? thanks

Comment: add sample data & desired result.

Comment: you gona right getdate()-1 return yesterday date.

Comment: @YogeshSharma i just want to return yesterdays results

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Is `DATE` column in both of tables? and can we see sample data please, we can't gues what cause the problem like that.

Comment: have tried with between to pass dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform

```
select DATEADD(day, -1, cast(SYSDATETIME() as DATE))
select dateadd(DD, -1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

then yesterday date is returned. Therefore, the only problem can be in the format of your [DATE] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
FROM
Person
JOIN Profit 
ON Person.id = Profit.id 
WHERE Table.[DATE] = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE() );
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be that [DATE] also needs converting :

```
FROM
    Person
JOIN 
    Profit 
ON 
    Person.id = Profit.id 
AND CAST([DATE] as Date) = CAST(getdate () -1  as Date)
```

Comment: `getdate () -1` return DATE, why you need to `CAST`?

Comment: @Sami 'getdate' alone will also return time etc. casting as date will return just the date, thats why i said also do it for [DATE] so they will both be the exact same format

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you do not want time part of date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
    JOIN Profit ON Person.id = Profit.id 
   AND [DATE] = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 106)
```

Answer (score 0):

if You have column with date:

```
SELECT * from Person p join Profit pr 
on (p.id = pr.person_id and pr.`date` = SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1))
```

Comment: which database server is this for? mySQL?

Comment: Yes it's mysql database.

Comment: @user8270653 The question tagged with SQL Server man, Can you see MySQL there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Between` as below :

```
FROM
Person
JOIN Profit 
ON Person.id = Profit.id 
AND [DATE] BETWEEN CONVERT(date, GETDATE()-1) AND CONVERT(date, GETDATE()-1)
```